# Use custom font in openxml created powerpoint parts (emf)

Tags: .net, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, metafile

we generate serverside pptx-documents with .net/c#. These pptx contain emf-images and some textfields. For drawing text we use custom fonts installed on the server. if we ship these pptx to our customers, we embed the fonts into the pptx and the textfields displayed correctly with the custom font.
The emf's were also created on the server and added to the document. These emf's could contain some text drawing with the custom font, but if the font is not installed on the customers computer powerpoint uses a system standard font. If the font is installed the emf text is correct.
It is possible to tell powerpoint to use the embedded font for emf's too?